# Read string after " " and before "(" using split in java

Tags: java, file, parsing, split

I have txt file with line:
1st line - 20-01-01 Abs Def est (xabcd)
2nd line - 290-01-01 Abs Def est ghj gfhj (xabcd fgjh fgjh)
3rd line - 20-1-1 Absfghfgjhgj (xabcd ghj 5676gyj)

I want to keep 3 diferent String array:

1. [0]20-01-01 [1]290-01-01 [2] 20-1-1
2. [0]Abs Def est [1]Abs Def est ghj gfhj [2] Absfghfgjhgj
3. [0]xabcd [1]xabcd fgjh fgjh [2] xabcd ghj 5676gyj

Using String[] array 1 = myLine.split(" ") i only have piece 20-01-01 but i also want to keep other 2 Strings

EDIT: I want to do this **using regular Expressions** (text file is large)

This is my piece of code:
Please help, i searching, but does not found anything
Thx.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class Holiday implements Comparable<Date>{

    Date date;
    String name;
    public Holiday(Date date, String name){
        this.date=date;
        this.name=name;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("c:/holidays.txt"));
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "windows-1251");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);



        TreeSet<Holiday> tr=new  TreeSet<>();

        System.out.println(br.readLine());
        String myLine = null;



        while ( (myLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        {  
            String[] array1 = myLine.split(" "); //OR use this
            //String array1 = myLine.split(" ")[0];//befor " " read 1-st string

            //String array2 = myLine.split("")[1];

            //Holiday h=new Holiday(array1, name)
            //String array1 = myLine.split(" ");
            // check to make sure you have valid data
          //  String[] array2 = array1[1].split(" ");

            System.out.println(array1[0]);
        }

    }




    @Override
    public int compareTo(Date o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Concatenating `1`, `2`, and `3` elements of `array1` with spaces in between will get you your 2nd string. The 3rd string is in `array1[4]`

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?) (.*?) (\\(.*\\))");
Matcher m = p.matcher("20-01-01 Abs Def est (abcd)");
if (!m.matches()) throw new Exception("Invalid string");
String s1 = m.group(1); // 20-01-01
String s2 = m.group(2); // Abs Def est
String s3 = m.group(3); // (abcd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringTokenizer, which has a " " as a delimiter by default.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be splitting based on whitespace. Each element of the string array would contain the individual whitespace-separate substrings, which you can then piece back together later on via string concatenation.

For instance,

`array1[0]` would be 20-01-01

`array1[1]` would be Abs

`array1[2]` would be Def

so on and so forth.

Another option is to Java regular expressions, but that may only be useful if your input text file is has a consistent formatting and if there's a lot of lines to process. It is very powerful, but requires some experience.

Answer (score 0):

Match required text data by regular expression.
The regexp below ensure there are exactly 3 words in the middle and 1 word in the bracket.

```
String txt = "20-01-01 Abs Def est hhh (abcd)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d) (\\w+ \\w+ \\w+) ([(](\\w)+[)])");

Matcher matcher = p.matcher(txt);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String s1 = matcher.group(1);
    String s2 = matcher.group(2);
    String s3 = matcher.group(3);
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(s2);
    System.out.println(s3);
}
```

However if you need more flexibility you may want to use code provided by Lence Java.